# 2002 BMW x5 won't start, does not click, no electrical power

Tags: electrical, bmw

My 2002 BMW x5 won't start. I checked the battery, it seems to be okay. Nothing electrical works in the entire car. What could cause this?

Comment: Did you by chance check the battery? More than likely this is your issue. Either it is flat or the connection is bad (might be corrosion at the terminals).

Comment: Exactly how wld we check it .? It has some type of power because the spar plugs sparked . I don't have a battery reader & tried looking for the battery only the positive connection is on top

Comment: Battery is in the trunk, more than likely. You'd need a multimeter to check the battery, though you can check the power level of the battery at the terminal you talk about (check between the terminal and ground). Also, what year/model is your Bimmer? We need more information to help you diagnose your situation. The battery is where I'd start, though.

Comment: It is an x5 2002

Comment: So, the battery in your case is under the cargo area where the spare tire is at. you'd have to take the spare out to replace it ... but you can probably check it with the spare in.

Comment: Had the car been working? Was it easy to start? If the answers are yes to those then it is very likely that something was left on that drained the battery. But before I jump to conclusions, it would be most helpful if you could tell more of the story – when did you last drive it? Anything unusual that you can think of?

Comment: Ground, in case you don't know, means a metal part of the car – for example the engine or a screw or bolt. This works because the negative terminal of the battery is connected to the body of the car. Doing that saves wire…

Comment: Can you jump start it?

Comment: I had been driving it nothing was wrong with only that oil level was really low but I did turn on the car put it in drive then it completely shut off. This has never happened

Comment: It's gonna be hard to get to the battery giving the fact that the trunk won't open -_- but I can try and do it from the inside

Comment: Is there any other way to open the trunk

Comment: The owners manual should have manual trunk release instructions.

Comment: My vehicle, same model, has just done the same, did you get an answer as to what happened?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a few things:

- Your **ignition switch** may not be making good electrical contact. Get a repair manual for your vehicle (not the owner's manual, a repair manual, from  Haynes or Chilton), they will tell you how to make a continuity test on your ignition switch (you will need a multimeter, $15 at WalMart)
- Your battery may not be **sending power** to the rest of the car. Disconnect the battery terminals, clean both the terminals and the posts with a steel wire brush. Make sure not to have something metallic touch the battery posts while doing this.
- Your battery **may only look fine**. Grab that multimeter and take a voltage reading of your battery with the car off. 12.6V is normal, 11.8V is pretty much the minimum you need to turn the car on. If it's too low, give your battery a boost and turn the car on. With the car on, take the battery voltage reading again, 14V is normal, if it's less than 13V your alternator isn't charging the battery. If everything is reading fine, turn absolutely everything electrical on (rear defrost, heater fan, headlights, radio) and take your reading again, it should drop to 13V. If everything looks fine, turn the car off and take that voltage reading again, you are expecting the same numbers as when you started this (12.6V). Anything less, your battery isn't holding a charge.

Comment: I was able to start my truck ('06 Silverado) with the battery nearly at 10vdc. I'm not saying your advice is bad, just saying you can do a lot with just a little bit of voltage today. I was seeing other issues which made me check the battery and get it replaced ultimately. Also, normal charging is dependent upon the vehicle make, but normally I've seen a good charging system running in the 14.1-14.6vdc arena. Anything over that and you're overcharging.

Comment: But the first thing to check is that the battery isn't run down. It could be a simple as a door being left open or the lights on (assuming no auto-shutoff) or some other load that got forgotten about.